# Create pdf from pdf-blob

Tags: jspdf

Is it possible to create a `pdf` document from a stored `pdf-blob` in my database? Something like:

```
function saveDatabaseBlob (blob) {
    var doc = new jsPDF("portrait", "mm", "a4", "compressPdf");
    doc.saveAs(blob, 'ZZZ.pdf');
}
```

Comment: What do you have in mind? Editing of the stored pdf or just sending it to the client?

Comment: I have generated a pdf and saved the blob in my database. Then the user should be able to load this blob from database and to download it again (as often as he like).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var file = new Blob(blob, { type : 'application/octet-stream' });
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = 'file_output.pdf'; 
a.click(); //for download
```

use Blob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob